# Am I violating encapsulation by having unit test access path to sql database file and creating a connector to it?

Tags: python, sql, oop, encapsulation

I have a python class that manages initilization, read, and writes to a sql database:

```
class Database {
  def __init__(self, path2db):
    # path2db is created within this constructor
    self._connector = # create a sqlite3 connector pointing to an input path2db 
  def query_col1(query_sql):
    # execute query_sql and return rows corresponding to the query
  def query_col2(query_sql):
    # execute query_sql and return rows corresponding to the query
  def write(rows):
    # write rows to db
}
```

For simplicity, let's assume this database table has 3 columns, `col1, col2, col3`, and we only have getters for 2 of them.

In the unit test, I want to query for `col3`, but we don't have a public facing getter for that, so I instead wrote my own getter:

```
def _query_col3(path2db):
  # implementation not included

def unit_test(tempdir):
  path2db = tempdir
  inputs = # define some inputs
  # call some methods and pass in inputs (some of the inputs are written to the db) and within those methods, a Database instance is generated and a path2db is formed and populated


  # now I want to test whether the table in path2db has the correct col3. 
  assert _query_col3(path2db) == (col3 from inputs)
```

I had a colleague suggest that I was breaking encapsulation by accessing `tempdir`, creating a connector to it that's outside of a `Database` instance.

Comment: Yes, your colleague is correct - it would be much better to create a Database instance, define a public function, and then verify the data using that function.  That way, you're testing the actual functionality of the database itself - not only the data

Comment: @Kelsey hmm, I don't quite understand this though. this seems to be suggesting that `path2db` is encapsulated, but it's an input, and I'm creating a separate connector to it? as for defining a public function to access `col3`, that doesn't make a lot of sense to me because that getter would only be used in unit tests. I don't think it's good practice to be defining public functions that are only used in unit tests